# How do we resolve the overlap among 3 Python and serial performance-related questions?

Tags: discussion

It was recently brought to my attention by [AlexE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users/1553/alexe) that my question [What tools or approaches are available to speed up code written in Python?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/what-tools-or-approaches-are-available-to-speed-up-code-written-in-python) might be a duplicate of (or overlap heavily with) [(how to) write simulations that run faster?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/how-to-write-simulations-that-run-faster).

In turn, [Dan](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users/81/dan) brought up that [(how to) write simulations that run faster?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/how-to-write-simulations-that-run-faster) might be a duplicate of [What are some good strategies for improving the serial performance of my code?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/what-are-some-good-strategies-for-improving-the-serial-performance-of-my-code).

Does anyone have any advice or opinions on how to deal with this overlap or duplication?

Points for discussion:

- [What are some good strategies for improving the serial performance of my code?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/what-are-some-good-strategies-for-improving-the-serial-performance-of-my-code) defines the scope really well, and the title can't get any better without getting longer (possibly unacceptably so). This question clearly focuses on low-level languages and serial performance.
- My question [What tools or approaches are available to speed up code written in Python?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/what-tools-or-approaches-are-available-to-speed-up-code-written-in-python) also attempts to define its scope well: I just want to know how to maximize the performance of Python, and I (try to) make it clear that the emphasis isn't on algorithms, but on automated methods (or even just general strategies) for reducing the overhead encountered when using an interpreted language.
- [(how to) write simulations that run faster?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/how-to-write-simulations-that-run-faster) is somewhat ambiguous in its intent. If you read the title, it looks a lot like it could be a duplicate of [What are some good strategies for improving the serial performance of my code?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/what-are-some-good-strategies-for-improving-the-serial-performance-of-my-code). But then when you read the body of the question, the author first mentions Python, then asks for general guidelines to make the program faster, tricks to do things in parallel, and resources. So it could also be a duplicate of [What tools or approaches are available to speed up code written in Python?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/what-tools-or-approaches-are-available-to-speed-up-code-written-in-python). There are many reasonable questions there, but the scope is large. The author mentions parallelism in there, which is something that neither of the two possible duplicate questions mention. They also ask for resources that a general scientist or engineer could understand; neither of the two possible duplicates attempts to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Questions often overlap IHMO you have a question about computer achitecture, a question about a specific programming language, and a question that seems really to be about algorithms (although answered as if it were the same as the first).  I don't see a problem with having all three on the site.